# Email titled "Top new Drupal Answers - Stack Exchange users for the week of Apr 18 2011" contains broken link.

Tags: bug, status-completed

> Hello,
>
> Congratulations -- you are one of the
>   top new Drupal Answers - Stack
>   Exchange users for the week of Apr 18
>   2011!
>
> http://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/drupal/2011-04-18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link seems correct to me. It links to the league page of the week containing April 18.

[image: screenshot]

On SE sites, the weeks are considered starting from Sunday, and ending on Saturday.

Comment: Ah, it's working now but was 404'ing when the email came through. I wonder if there's some lag time involved.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this was a bug on our end and has been fixed.

We also clarified in the email, if you have < 200 rep, that only >= 200 rep users are tracked in the network-wide leagues.